# Daily dose of recommended water

Tags: diet, terminology, water

Here (https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/how-much-water-should-you-drink) it says to drink four-to-six cup of water.

I find it weird that they don't mention how big the cup should be? **How many liters should the cup contain? 0.2L?**

I've seen other places mentioning cups. So what size are cups assumed in such cases?

Comment: Are you talking about the size of a glass of water or a cup measurement as in baking?

Answer (score 4):

A cup is a non-standard unit of measurement for volume:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_(unit)

It usually varies between 200ml and 250ml.

In the U.S., it is 2.365882365 decilitres exactly (which is 236.5882365 millilitres exactly).

Comment: Seeing as the OP is using a US source, maybe you could point out the US standard for a 1 cup measure?

Comment: @ChrisRogers; have done

Comment: lol... he's talking about something to hold the water. Not a volumetric size. He's asking how big the cup should be. i.e. 8oz 12oz 16oz (or ml)

Comment: @jbrahy - The OP may be asking how big the cup should be, but the answer explains that the cup being mentioned in many sources is a unit of fluid volume measurement.  Perfectly good answer and explanation.